# How to get response time on d2r-query of D2RQ?

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, d2rq

I'm using d2r-query of D2RQ to make some SPARQL Query, I'm using commande line. Please, how can I get a response time?

```
d2r-query myMappedData.ttl "SELECT * {?s ?p ?o} LIMIT 1000"
```

Is there other tools to use to get the response time?

Comment: `time d2r-query myMappedData.ttl "SELECT * {?s ?p ?o} LIMIT 1000"` for the whole command. Anything beyond has to be done in source code. clearly, you could also check in your database log if enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have found a solution and I would shar it with you. So you should edit the d2_quey.java file and get the date before and after the query code treatment and calculate the timeAfterTreatment - timeBeforeTreatment

Like the code bellow :

```
Object objStartTime=System.currentTimeMillis(); 
Long startTime=(objStartTime==null)?0:(Long)objStartTime;
```

Before this code (Treatment query)

```
QueryEngineD2RQ.register();
Query q = QueryFactory.create(query, loader.getResourceBaseURI());
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q, d2rqModel);
if (timeout > 0) {
        qe.setTimeout(Math.round(timeout * 1000));
}
QueryExecUtils.executeQuery(q, qe, ResultsFormat.lookup(format));
```

And add this code in the end

```
Object objEndTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
Long endTime=(objEndTime==null)?0:(Long)objEndTime;
Long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
// display response time
System.out.println("============================================");
System.out.println("Response time : "+totalTime+" ms ");
System.out.println("============================================");
```

Good luck